# How to add specified duration to string date in Swift 5

Tags: swift, date, time, swift5, duration

So I have a function that converts a specified local time, to UTC (Time starts and ends as a string)

I need to add a duration (lets say 1.5 hours) to this time, which may end up going into the next day so I believe I need to use Calendar, and not timeInterval.

I'm a little clueless on how this is done, the documentation isn't the greatest on this and I'm not good with Swift.

Here is what I have so far.

```
import Foundation


func localToUTC(date:String, originTimeZone:String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: originTimeZone)
    
    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
    
    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)

}

print(localToUTC(date: "05/01/2021 15:37", originTimeZone: "America/Boise"))
```

Just to be clear, I am trying to add another parameter to my function (or make a new function, doesn't matter) to add a duration to the UTC time that my current function outputs.

To put things into context, let's say a flight departs at 15:37 local time (Boise, for example, which is +6 for UTC conversion).

So the flight departs at 21:37 UTC on 5/1/2021. The flight duration is 4 hours.

I would like an output of 5/2/2021 01:37 UTC.

Comment: Your code doesn't add any duration, so I assume you haven't done that part yet? What type is the duration that you want to add? `TimeInterval`? `DateComponents`? `String` If it is `String`, what format is it in?

Comment: I believe I want to use ``DateComponents``. I'm just not sure on how to do that while integrating it with my current function.  The format is ``MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`` Long story short, I need to add time to the output of my current function. I think ``DateComponents`` is correct in case the time pushes into the next day.

Comment: Just taking ``MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`` and adding something such as 90 minutes. I'm not sure what inputs swift can take, but if I could add it in minutes that would be preferred, although it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to add a new parameter to `localToUTC` that represents some period of time that you want to add to the instant represented by the first parameter, and you want to output the result as a UTC string. Correct?

Comment: That is the objective. It doesn't have to be a new parameter to ``localToUTC``, but that way is probably preferred. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Whether to use `TimeInterval` or `DateComponents` doesn't depend on whether the result goes into the next day or not. It depends on whether you want to add things like "1 month" or "10 days", which can't be represented by a number of seconds (months and days can have varying lengths).

Comment: Just trying to add small intervals (hours, not days or months)

Comment: @f1racer328 Note that you probably meant 01:37 in your post

Comment: Yep, just fixed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the flight duration to the resulting date object. Note also that you shouldn't force unwrap the result as it might crash your app. Make sure to return nil in case you pass an invalid string. Something like:

```
func localToUTC(date: String, originTimeZone: String, duration: TimeInterval) -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
    guard let timezone = TimeZone(identifier: originTimeZone) else { return nil }
    dateFormatter.timeZone = timezone
    guard let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else { return nil }
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    return dateFormatter.string(from: dt.addingTimeInterval(duration))
}
```

---

```
print(localToUTC(date: "05/01/2021 15:37", originTimeZone: "America/Boise", duration: 4 * 60 * 60) ?? "nil")
```

---

This will print

> 05/02/2021 01:37

Comment: Sorry if I poorly explained what I'm trying to do. I'm just trying to add a specified duration to the output of my function. So the output is 21:37, but I want to add 2 hours to that UTC time and get 23:37.

Comment: This is it, thanks for all of the help! - Just a pilot trying to automate his logbook imports (Company doesn't give UTC times ^_^, but that's what my logbook uses) Thanks again.

Comment: @f1racer328 don't forget to set the `DateFormatter`'s `locale` to `en_US_POSIX` when parsing a fixed date format before setting the `dateFormat`.